# Запрос API телеграм бота (aiogram) с ubuntu сервера

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, api

Не смог, как ни пытался, найти решение в интернете своей проблемы. Суть такая: выполняю код с домашнего компьютера Windows 10 и запрос осуществляется, заливаю этот же код на сервер ubuntu (хостинг) - не работает.

Использую:
import requests
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError, Timeout, TooManyRedirects
import json
(остальной код примерно как в инструкции на https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#section/Quick-Start-Guide)

В try-except получаю:
`HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pro-api.coinmarketcap.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest?slug=everscale&convert=RUB (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fc04d413850>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable'))`

На сайте в лк койнмаркеткапа не показывает обращения через API с сервера, то есть с сервера он не уходит даже по всей видимости.
Пробовал:

```
$ sudo ufw allow 80
$ sudo ufw allow 443
$ sudo ufw allow http
$ sudo ufw allow https
```

Пробовал всякие задержки ставить и несколько запросов - нет результата.
Еще пишут про прокси - это не пробовал/не умею и не особо понимаю почему это должно было бы помочь.
Был бы очень благодарен за наводку, так как мои идеи куда гуглить исчерпались. Может как-то логи записать и так проблему решить?

---

UPD:
Проблема кажется в том, что мой сервер использует IPv6, а coinmarketcap IPv4.

Ответ поддержки моего хостинга:

```
Для данного домена есть только IPv4 адрес 104.17.141.178.

IPv6 адреса нет.
```

Есть ли какие-то возможности обойти это?

Comment: А хоть что нть с сервера уходит? Попингуйте для начала.

Comment: PING www.yandex.ru(yandex.ru (2a02:6b8:a::a)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from yandex.ru (2a02:6b8:a::a): icmp_seq=1 ttl=45 time=174 ms
//
** ping www.pro-api.coinmarketcap.com
ping: www.pro-api.coinmarketcap.com: Name or service not known
//
**  ping https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest
ping: https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest: Name or service not known

Comment: Вы что пингуете? У вас `pro-api.coinmarketcap.com` используется.

Comment: pro-api.coinmarketcap.com мне и нужен. Яндекс был для проверки. Я обновил вводную информацию на счет IPv4-6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в том, что мой хостинг не имел IPv4, а лишь IPv6, при этом API coinmarketcup работает только через IPv4.